# CKEditor cannot show my country's special characters Æ Ø Å

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ckeditor

I am using the CKEditor for a better experience when writing articles. The problem is, that it is using some kind of code instead of the true letters which are æ, ø and å.

This is how it translates in my mysql database, when sending data from the CKEditor to my database:

æ = `&aelig;`

ø = `&oslash;`

å = `&aring;`

How can I change this? The meta is set to utf_8.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```js
<script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'article', {
    language: 'da'
});
</script>
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea name="article" style="height:600px; width:90%;"></textarea>
</body>
```

I hope someone can help me!

**EDIT**
Adding data to the database:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$name = addslashes($_POST[writersName]);
$uid = addslashes($_POST[writersUid]);
$article = addslashes($_POST[article]);
$category = addslashes($_POST[category]);



$sql = "INSERT INTO artikler (name, uid, article, category)
VALUES ('".$name."', '".$uid."', '".$article."', '".$category."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("Location: addArticle.php?name=1");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Since the characters getting change in the backend it's better to show the backend code and not the frontend.

Comment: Well the table in my phpmyadmin database is set to `utf8_danish_ci` which should be correct?

Comment: Your table might have the correct charset/collate, but it doesn't mean that the insert/encoding in your backend is correct.

Comment: @Dekel absolutely no expert in this area. How can I have a look at this?

Comment: As already wrote - add the backend code (php/python/ruby/.net/whatever language you use for your backend)

Comment: @Dekel I have added the php code now

Comment: Did you check what content the POST data contains? It will be great to know if the content is changed at the backend (using PHP) or front end (by the ckeditor itself).

Comment: When I echo ´$article´ in the php code I get the right characters

Comment: Did you check this in the source (view-source)? Or is that what you see in your page?

Comment: That is what it displays on the page. How do I check on the view source?

Comment: inspect element/right click view-source :)

Comment: Haha :D Well the view source is showing the wrong characters...

Comment: So it looks like the ckeditor itself sends the wrong data.

Comment: Great.. Do you know how I can change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we know that the problem is with the CKEditor itself, you can try this config:

```
entities = false;
```

And inside the CKEditor:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'article', {
        language: 'da',
        entities: false
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!!